# adding vectors of unequal length

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have hundreds of vectors of unequal length that I need to sum, what is the cleanest way to do so?

So, if I have as input

```
inp={{a,b,c,d},{e,f,g},{h}}
```

I want the answer

```
{a+e+h,b+f,c+g,d}
```

I can see how to do this by finding the length of the longest element and then using `PadRight[]` to make the others match, like so

```
Total[Map[PadRight[#, Max[Map[Length[#] &, inp]]] &, inp]]
```

but this feels inelegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: Your method is exactly what came to mind (before I saw yours). Okay, call me inelegant..

Comment: @Simon Woods the Ragged Transpose solution in the other thread is exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Flatten` to transpose the ragged array, then `Total`:

```
Total[Flatten[inp, {{2}, {1}}], {2}]
(* {a + e + h, b + f, c + g, d} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about elegant but...

```
Reap[Nest[(Sow[Total[Map[First,#]]];Map[Rest[#]/.{}:>Sequence[]&,#])&,inp,4]][[2,1]]
```

Loosing the hard-coded 4...

```
Reap[NestWhile[(Sow[Total[Map[First,#]]];Map[Rest[#]/.{}:>Sequence[]&,#])&,inp,Length[#]>0&]][[2,1]]
```

Comment: Is there a specific way of moving an answer or do I just repost it there?